# Foreign key violation error during migration with EF Core

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have two tables - one is `BuldingStory,` and the other is `Building.` I have already had the `BuildingStory` table created and has some data in it.

Now I am adding a building table along with foreign key relationships to the `BuildingStory`.

Here are the table's structure:

```
public class BuildingStory : IIdentity<string>
{
    public Building Building { get; set; }  
    public Guid BuildingId { get; set; } // this is the new column added
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Space> Spaces { get; set; }
}   

public class Building : IIdentity<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BuildingStory> BuildingStories { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the existing  fluent configuration included in `OnModelCreating()` method for `BuildingStory`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BuildingStory>()
                .HasKey(b => new { b.Id, b.ProjectNumber });

modelBuilder.Entity<BuildingStory>()
            .HasMany(b => b.Spaces)
            .WithOne(s => s.BuildingStory)
            .HasForeignKey(s => new { s.BuildingStoryId, s.ProjectNumber })
            .IsRequired();
```

Now I have added a `building` table  with the fluent configuration like as below

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Building>()
            .HasKey(b => new { b.Id, b.ProjectNumber });
     
modelBuilder.Entity<Building>()
            .HasMany(b => b.BuildingStories)
            .WithOne(bs => bs.Building)
            .HasForeignKey(bs => new { bs.BuildingId, bs.ProjectNumber })
            .IsRequired();
```

I am using PostgreSQL with EF Core code first approach; I ran the migration, and it got generated the migration file with the code as below

```
  ......
  ......  
  migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_BuildingStories_Buildings_BuildingId_ProjectNumber",
            table: "BuildingStories",
            columns: new[] { "BuildingId", "ProjectNumber" },
            principalTable: "Buildings",
            principalColumns: new[] { "Id", "ProjectNumber" },
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

Now I am getting an error when I try to update the database using `update-database`. I get this error:

> Insert or update on table "BuildingStories" violates foreign key constraint "FK_BuildingStories_Buildings_BuildingId_ProjectNumber"

Could anyone please let me know what could be the possible solution to avoid this error during the update to the database?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't get it. Building and BuildingStory are already relationally linked using a guid - what does adding a string and making a compound key at both ends bring, other than pain?

Comment: Hmm, that is for a different purpose. On migration, I am getting violation error

Comment: @CaiusJard, apart from that, is there any way to avoid this error? Deleting the data on the building story will fix the issue?

Comment: If you already have data in the BuildingStory table, then you need to add the Building table without the FK. Then add data to the Building table. And last, add the FK.

Comment: Another option is to remove the data from the BuildingStory table first, then do the migration and then re-add all data.

Comment: I am already adding that foreign key with default guid

Comment: My guess is you don't yet have a building with a matching default guid.

Comment: yup, there is no data for the building table, and it is a new table altogether

Comment: So in that case which one is feasible to proceed

Comment: Surely if you're adding a foreign key to a table you've already created the parent table with data that the child will relate to before you make the relation?

Comment: I have tried to back up the data for the building story, then deleted the information for the building story, ran the migration, and tried to add the data back to the building story table, and this approach did not work

Answer (score 0):

Approach A:

1. Add the `BuildingId` column to the `BuildingStory` table and assign it with the appropriate value. You will need to determine upfront which stories belong to the same building and assign all of these the same Guid value.
2. Backup the `BuildingStory` table to a temp table.
3. Delete the `BuildingStory` table.
4. Create the `Building` table and insert all the buildings that you defined `Guid`s for in step 1.
5. Recreate the `BuildingStory` table.
6. Add the FK to the `BuildingStory` table.
7. Copy the data from the temp table to the `BuildingStory` table.

Approach B:

1. Create a data migration script for the current contents of the `BuildingStory` table.
2. Delete the `BuildingStory` table.
3. Run the EF migrations.
4. Add data to the `Building` table.
5. Modify the script created in step 1 and add the appropriate BuildingId `Guid`'s
6. Run the script to fill `BuildingStory` again.

Comment: In all those cases, I don't have any data for building table

Comment: You cannot NOT have data for the primary table (Building). Is your plan to add the table and then fill in this data later? In that case you won't be able to apply the FK, because it serves as a constraint that a `BuildingStory` can only exist if there is a parent `Building`.

Only option then is to forgo on the FK. Fill the `BuildingStory` table and give each row the empty Guid for BuildingId. Then add a single `Building` with Id also the empty Guid.

Comment: Which, again, kind of defeats the purpose of having a `Building` table at all. At some time you will have to figure out to which Building each story belongs... Then add each of those buildings and update the appropriate `BuildingStory` records.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I will look into  the alternatives